# how to close recaptcha code after send phone otp

Tags: firebase

**Firebase phone auth verification**I have created a mobile app using flutter and added phone number verification using firebase authenticate. However, When I trying to sign in by providing the phone number, It goes to web page and shows RECAPTCHA. After few seconds it sends the OTP. How can I prevent from the RECPTCHA?

[thi page close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEgiA.png)